# Google Visualization Timeline Chart sorting by two columns

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I get this timeline to sort by two columns, "RouteName" then "PPF" ?

Ideally, I would really prefer it to sort "PLAN" first then the others.  As is, it's sorting by "RouteName" then "Start" date/time.

Thanks as always for the assistance!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
})
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart)

function drawChart() {

  const container = document.getElementById('divTimeline')
  const chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container)

  //#region ORIGINAL HARD CODED VERSION
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'RouteName' }) //Row label
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'PPF' }) //Bar label (optional)
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' }) //Tooltip (optional)
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'style', role: 'style' }) //Style (optional)
  data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' }) //Start
  data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' }) //End
  data.addRows([
    ['FORD M4421', 'PLAN', null, 'color: black', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 50, 0), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 15, 10, 0)],
    ['FORD M4421', 'PASS', null, 'color: green', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 14, 17, 39), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 14, 32, 15)],

    ['FORD M4404', 'PLAN', null, 'color: black', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 7, 50, 0), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 9, 10, 0)],
    ['FORD M4404', 'PASS', null, 'color: green', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 8, 23, 21), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 8, 43, 32)],

    ['CEVA DAILY', 'PLAN', null, 'color: black', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 05, 0), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 14, 10, 0)],
    ['CEVA DAILY', 'FAILED', null, 'color: red', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 9, 46, 27), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 9, 54, 57)],

    ['CEVA DAILY', 'PLAN', null, 'color: black', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 05, 0), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 14, 10, 0)],
    ['CEVA DAILY', 'FAILED', null, 'color: red', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 12, 58, 26), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 19, 49)],

    ['CEVA DAILY', 'PLAN', null, 'color: black', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 05, 0), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 14, 10, 0)],
    ['CEVA DAILY', 'PASS', null, 'color: green', new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 11, 46), new Date(2022, 6, 27, 13, 29, 26)],
  ])
  //#endregion

  data.sort([
    { column: 0, desc: false }, //sort RouteName
    { column: 1, desc: false }, //sort PPF
  ])

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      format: 'M/d\r\nHH:mm',
      gridlines: { count: 24 },
      minValue: new Date(2022, 6, 27, 0, 0, 0),
      maxValue: new Date(2022, 6, 29, 0, 0, 0),
    },
    height: 800,
    isHtml: true,
    timeline: { groupByRowLabel: true },
  }

  chart.draw(data, options)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="divTimeline"></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, the timeline is always going to sort by date, within each row label. all you can really do is, provide a date that gives the sort order you need, then create a custom tooltip that displays the real date. assuming all events are on the same date and time is the only difference...

Comment: BOO, I guess I will suffix my row labels with the words "PLAN" and "RESULT".  It will then sort the labels before the dates.  Thanks for the hint. (ps...If you want,  copy/paste your response as answer and I will check it off) Thanks again!!